# Extends UserManager in Symfony2 with FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony, extends, fosuserbundle

I tried to extend the UserManager of FOS according to this [link](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/logging_by_username_or_email.md)

My service is correctly detected but i have an error i can't resolved :

```
ErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to FOS\UserBundle\Entity\UserManager::__construct() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\EncoderFactoryInterface, none given, called in
```

MyUserManager :

```
namespace ChoupsCommerce\UserBundle\Model;

use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\UserManager;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;

class MyUserManager extends UserManager
{
    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {
        $user = $this->findUserByUsernameOrEmail($username);

        if (!$user) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(sprintf('No user with name "%s" was found.', $username));
        }

        return $user;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you found a workaround ? I have exactly the same problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Not really, i just stop using FOS and I simply use Symfony2 login system.

Comment: Did you try my solution?

Comment: At least, your solution doesn't work for me :'(

Answer (score 18):

I had the same problem, here is my solution (basically a combination of the first two answers):

Set up service in config.yml, don't forget the arguments

```
services:
    custom_user_manager:
        class: Acme\UserBundle\Model\CustomUserManager
        arguments: [@security.encoder_factory, @fos_user.util.username_canonicalizer, @fos_user.util.email_canonicalizer, @fos_user.entity_manager, Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User]
```

Then connect service to FOS user_manager (also in config.yml):

```
fos_user:
    service:
        user_manager: custom_user_manager
```

In the CustomUserManager recall the construct-method, like gilden said:

```
class CustomUserManager extends UserManager{

    public function __construct(EncoderFactoryInterface $encoderFactory, CanonicalizerInterface $usernameCanonicalizer, CanonicalizerInterface $emailCanonicalizer, ObjectManager $om, $class)
    {
        parent::__construct($encoderFactory, $usernameCanonicalizer, $emailCanonicalizer, $om, $class);
    }

}
```

Comment: You can use the parameter value `%fos_user.model.user.class%` instead of the hard coded entity class name as the last constructor argument.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add the constructor method (`__construct`) and pass the required arguments down to the base class:

```php
namespace ChoupsCommerce\UserBundle\Model;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\UserManager;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\EncoderFactoryInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Util\CanonicalizerInterface;

class MyUserManager extends UserManager
{
    public function __construct(
        EncoderFactoryInterface $encoderFactory,
        CanonicalizerInterface $usernameCanonicalizer,
        CanonicalizerInterface $emailCanonicalizer,
        EntityManager $em,
        $class
    ) {
        parent::__construct($encoderFactory, $usernameCanonicalizer, $emailCanonicalizer, $em, $class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry my English is poor.

May be your custom manager service's arguments is wrong because it says

`Argument 1 passed to FOS\UserBundle\Entity\UserManager::__construct() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\EncoderFactoryInterface, none given, called in`

Here is my config:

```
iep_core.iep_user_manager:   
     class: Iep\CoreBundle\Service\IepUserManager
     arguments: [@security.encoder_factory, @fos_user.util.username_canonicalizer, @fos_user.util.email_canonicalizer, @fos_user.entity_manager, Iep\CoreBundle\Entity\User]
```