# FOSUserBundle: Trying to check for "deleted" flag before login

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

Im trying to figure out where exactly to hook into the FOSUserBundle Login-process to check wether a user has the "deleted" flag and if its true, terminate the login-attempt returning an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, Authentication is handled by security component not by FOS User bundle.
For more information first read this [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/security.html)

**Short Summary here**

```
firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true
```

> When a user makes a request to a URL that's protected by a firewall,
>   the security system is activated. The job of the firewall is to
>   determine whether or not the user needs to be authenticated, and if he
>   does, to send a response back to the user initiating the authentication process.

SRC: http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/security.html#how-security-works-authentication-and-authorization

```
providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username
```

Firewall needs a provider (which provider username & password). FOS user bundle has its own user provider.

**Your problem**
You can extend the user manager of fos user bundle and overwrite the logic to check more conditions.

You can see the sample here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14985093/598424

**Now How to check delete flag**

> The `AdvancedUserInterface` interface adds four extra methods to validate the account status:
>
> - `isAccountNonExpired()` checks whether the user's account has expired,
> - `isAccountNonLocked()` checks whether the user is locked,
> - `isCredentialsNonExpired()` checks whether the user's credentials (password) has expired,
> - `isEnabled()` checks whether the user is enabled.

[How to create our own custom provider?](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html)

Comment: Thank you for this Hint! 
I extended the usermanager class and edited findUserBy-method that it checks for deleted and then empty the $criteria array it uses, let it go. 

It then returns to login-screen with standard error (User doesnt exist). Works.