# Is there any way to select user with custom selector (find method)?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

I'm using `FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle` (Doctrine). All works fine, except I would like to select user with my custom selector (find method) because I would like to make some joints.

Is there any way better then `FoS` bundle code changes?

**UPDATE:**

I know about the possibility to use custom `findOneBy...` (from my own repository class), but I think this way is incorrect: when you see this method's definition you don't expect some side-effects and if you redeclare it you will always have them. From my point of view, I should make some method `findOneBy...Join...` and use it inside custom `UserManager` or some sort of its delegate to retrieve in controller with `$this->getUser()`.

**UPDATE2:**
After I found the solution... I don't think that my question is duplicate of [Extends UserManager in Symfony2 with FOSUserBundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9806379/extends-usermanager-in-symfony2-with-fosuserbundle). Yes, extending is the key, but in that question it's discussed how to extend (some specific class) and in mine I got answer that extension is what I need. I mean that it's hard to find that solution with the question, similar to mine (at least, I tried before asking).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extends UserManager in Symfony2 with FOSUserBundle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9806379/extends-usermanager-in-symfony2-with-fosuserbundle)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that you are processing selects/inserts/updates through the [FOSUB UserManager](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/user_manager.html),
i.e. `$this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');` and its `findUserByXXX`.

To do that, Put12co22mer2 is right, the first thing you need is to create a [custom Repository class](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes).

The methods `findUserByXXX` use the `EntityRepository::findOneBy` method.
So, you can modify the behavior of the `UserManager::findUserBy` methods by simply recreating the default `findOneBy` method in your custom Repository.

Example:

```
// src/UserBundle/Entity/Repository/YourUserRepository.php

/**
 * Custom findOneBy.
 */
public function findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)
{
    // Build you custom Query with additional joins
}
```

Like this, the default `UserManager::findUserByXXX` methods will use your `YourUserRepository::findOneBy` method, and so you get the expected result by calling them.

If you want to add some custom methods to the `UserManager`, [override it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9806379/extends-usermanager-in-symfony2-with-fosuserbundle).

Comment: Updated my question, will be glad if you can check

Comment: I given a link at the end of my answer that shows you how extend the UserManager, you should do your custom method like this. Plus, the two way I given are the only alternative to change the behavior of getUser from a Controller.

Answer (score 2):

You can define your own custom repository ?

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as FosUser;

/**
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Project\XBundle\Entity\Repository\UserRepository")
* @ORM\Table(name="users")
*/
class User extends FosUser
{   
}
```

For using the custom repository, the best is the [official doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes).

**UPDATE :**

Here is the link about [FOSUserManager](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/user_manager.html), why don't create a new service extending the default manager, and insert your own methods ?

You're doing this :

```
$userManager = $container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
```

If you create your own class extending `FOS\UserBundle\Doctrine\UserManager` and mount it as service, you'll be able to call

```
$users =  $container
                   ->get('your.super.new.user.manager.service')
                   ->findByMyNewSuperMethod($args);
```

- Link to the [doctrine Fos services](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/doctrine.xml) for service arguments...

---

**UPDATE 2 :**
I didn't see the @chalasr answer, but he show you the way,there is better, [Overriding the User Manager](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/user_manager.html#overriding-the-user-manager), the official documentation about this case...*

*Extract :*

> You can replace the default implementation of the user manager by
>   defining a service implementing
>   FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface and setting its id in the
>   configuration. The id of the default implementation is
>   fos_user.user_manager.default

```
fos_user:
    # ...
    service:
        user_manager: custom_user_manager_id
```

Comment: Updated my question, will be glad if you can check

Comment: To override the UserManager, the answer I given is morr complete than the official doc that shows the service declaration only.

Comment: @chalasr you're right, this question should be closed as duplicate so.